# Terminology: Point on the edge of convex polygon in the direction of a given point

Tags: geometry, terminology, centroid

Consider a convex polygon *P* with centroid *c* and a point *p*. 
Let *q* be the closest point to *p* on the line segment from *p* to *c* that is a member of *P*.

[image: Line between centroid and point outside the simplex]

What do you call the point q?  What do you call this operation?

Context: I am a non-mathematician working on an AI application, who just wants to know the correct name for things.

Comment: I'm calling it "centroid projection" for now.